# How to get xml element values to a string using Xdocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, c#-4.0

I am storing a xml in a string and using Xdocument i am parsing the string to xml from that i need to get xml element values and using that values i need to insert it in db. Any help would be appreciated.

**XML:**

```
<ListInventorySupplyResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01/">
- <ListInventorySupplyResult>
- <InventorySupplyList>
- <member>
  <SellerSKU>043859634910</SellerSKU> 
  <FNSKU>X000IA4045</FNSKU> 
  <ASIN>B005YV4DJO</ASIN> 
  <Condition>NewItem</Condition> 
  <TotalSupplyQuantity>10</TotalSupplyQuantity> 
  <InStockSupplyQuantity>10</InStockSupplyQuantity> 
- <EarliestAvailability>
  <TimepointType>Immediately</TimepointType> 
  </EarliestAvailability>
  <SupplyDetail /> 
  </member>
  </InventorySupplyList>
  </ListInventorySupplyResult>
- <ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>d50af29d-f203-4efc-a864-1725a59ded97</RequestId> 
  </ResponseMetadata>
  </ListInventorySupplyResponse>
```

**Code:**

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(a);
string Sku = xd.Element();
var ASIN = xd.Descendants("ASIN");
var Condition = xd.Descendants("Condition");
var TotalSupplyQuantity = xd.Descendants("TotalSupplyQuantity");
```

Comment: I'd suggest you start by writing a little more code as five lines won't write to the database by themselves.

Comment: what is the problem. what error you receive in above code, please share

Comment: @patel I just wanted to know how to set a particular xml node value to a string

Answer (score 2):

You should use the xml namespace `http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01/`

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01/";

var condition = (string)xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Condition").First();
```

---

**OR**

you can search for `Tag` *Condition* in *any* xml namespace

```
var condition2 = (string)xDoc.Descendants()
                             .First(d => d.Name.LocalName == "Condition");
```

---

**OR**

you can use XPath to get *Condition* in *any* xml namespace

```
var condition3 = (string)xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//*[local-name()='Condition']");
```

Comment: Look up GetDefaultNamespace() for less typos.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
string value = xd.Root.Element("SellerSKU").Value;
```